# Redundant newlines in Documentation proposed changes reviewer list

Tags: bug, documentation, design, documentation-proposals, safari

On the [Proposed Changes page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python?tab=proposedchanges&subtab=approved) in Safari on macOS, each reviewer takes a newline, which makes the page a bit weird looking:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I [can't reproduce this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5yn5.png) on Win 10 / Chrome.

Comment: @Cerbrus This is why I tagged my question with [tag:safari], the last but one browser I would use.

Comment: Can reproduce! For some reason that's not immediately obvious, each `<a>` is styled as `display: block`.

Comment: They’re all `display: flex`. `display: inline-flex` will allow them to use flexbox, but not break the layout.